# Reference a parent table for a Navigation Property in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, navigation-properties

I essentially have three tables with FK's

Make

- MakeId
- MakeName

Model

- ModelId
- ModelName
- MakeId (FK)

Vehicle

- VehicleId
- DatePurchased
- ModelId (FK)

I would like a navigation property from Vehicle to Make without modifying my database

I tried:

```
public class Make
{
    public int MakeId {get;set;}
    <snip>...</snip>
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicles {get;set;}

}

<snip>Model</snip>

public class Vehicle
{
    public int VehicleId {get;set}
    <snip>...</snip>
    public virtual Make VehicleMake {get;set;}
}


public class VehicleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Vehicle>
{
    public VehicleMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.VehicleId);
        <snip>...</snip>
        this.HasRequired(t => t.VehicleMake)
        .WithMany(t => t.Vehicles)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.Model.MakeId);
    }

}
```

However when I did this I received an exception:

> The properties expression 'd => d.Model.MakeId' is not valid.   The
>   expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty' 
>   VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple
>   properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1,
>   t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New From { t.MyProperty1,
>   t.MyProperty2 }'.

How can I create a navigation property on my Make & Vehicle tables without adding Vehicle.ModelId column to my database?

Answer (score 2):

EF does not support that type of modeling. You can create a property that wraps around `Model.Make` as follows. But it may lead to unnecessary lazy loading.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int VehicleId {get;set}
    <snip>...</snip>

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Make VehicleMake 
    {
        get { return Model.Make; }
        set { Model.Make = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is ok, I understand this, but how can I get the Make.Vehicles to map properly?

Comment: @NathanKoop Same issue with that also. You cannot map it. Workaround would be to query the database and assign it manually when you require that property.

Comment: thanks for your effort, I'll do some further work and post any updates here.