# Database relation traversing multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

I would like to expand on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524819/reference-a-parent-table-for-a-navigation-property-in-ef) in terms of performance. The db schema was:

Make

- MakeId
- MakeName

Model

- ModelId
- ModelName
- MakeId (FK)

Vehicle

- VehicleId
- DatePurchased
- ModelId (FK)

If I want to know the *Make* of a *Vehicle* I would need to traverse over the Model table using Vehicle.Model.Make. Let's assume I have not three but 4 or 5 tables which are connected this way, so that I would have to write e.g. InvoiceForVehicle.Vehicle.Model.Make. This would result in bad query performance, I think.

I could add an additional column *MakeId (FK)* to the InvoiceForVehicle table which goes directly to the make. This would mean I have duplicate data and that every time I change the relation between the InvoiceForVehicle and a vehicle I would have to update the *MakeId (FK)* accordingly.

InvoiceForVehicle

- InvoiceId
- DateCreated
- VehicleId (FK)
- MakeId (FK)

Is that a good idea?

Comment: How often is this query invoked?  Does it have to be real time, or is this similar to a monthly/daily report that gets accessed all the time?  How many records are there?

Comment: I think ~10k rows for table Make and each has of it has ~3 Model each has ~3 Vehicle and so on. The Make of an InvoiceForVehicle would be accessed almost always when an InvoiceForVehicle is queried. About 50 users are using the db at the same time.

Comment: How long does it take for the current query to return?

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I must admit that we currently are using the latter option ('duplicate' FKs) in our application :(. I asked the question the other way round for simplicity. So probably we should drop the 'duplicate' keys and profile some adapted queries to decide whether we can get back to a consistent database schema without dropping too much performance?

Comment: Well the reason why I ask, is that if it is computationally expensive to do this and it happens all the time, a materialized view may be your best bet if the indexes aren't paying off.

Comment: I think you're being too fearful of joins. Get your indexing right and audit the execution plans. You'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons: *Maybe*

For consistency reasons: **No**

Using what you suggest, it will be possible to have a Vehicle that's connected to a Make that doesn't correspond to (the Model of) that Vehicle!

You could try to use composite (and maybe natural) keys all the way down, with corresponding composite foreign keys. The important foreign key in this case would be the one going from `Vehicle (MakeId, ModelId)` to `Model (MakeId, ModelId)`.

Comment: I would really like to avoid composite keys. But am I right assuming they would provide consistency in this case?

Comment: Yes, you are right. (As long as you also use composite foreign keys. But you knew that already.)

Comment: @Jared: Well, my point is mainly about consistency, anyway. Maybe your comment really should be directed at the question?

Comment: It is.  I think we essentially said the same thing.  Yours including an alternative db design though.  However, even without factoring in EF. At the point that you have an invoice you will be pulling the other tables off of the ID and not "really" searching I just don't see how anything over what he already has will be beneficial.  I wasn't attacking your answer though and I'm sorry if it came off like that.  Given proper joins/indexes he'd be fine as is.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will see much of a hit (if any) since you will be referencing by an ID and not doing any actual searching.

I think (based on my knowledge) that your existing model is structured more correctly then the new proposed solution.  You shouldn't put yourself in a situation where you can lose data integrity like your new solution would allow.

So to answer your question.  No, I don't think the new idea is a good solution.  Your existing setup is more "correct" based on database normal form.  Also, since `Entity Framework` lazy loads data you won't actually be running any queries that aren't needed.